How to solve this second order ODE with variable coefficients?
In my work, I encountered the following ODE:
$(x+c)^2 y^{''}(x) + (a (x+c) + b) y^{'}(x) = 0, \quad y(0) = 1, \quad y(\infty) = 0,$
where  $a ,  b ,$ and  $c$  are real constants. I made the substitution  $u = x + c$ , which transformed the equation to:
$u^2 y^{''}(u) + (a u + b) y^{'}(u) = 0.$
The transformation $u=z^{-1}, y=z^k e^z w(z)$ reduces it further. I would appreciate any guidance on solving this equation with the given boundary conditions with any other kind of transformation.

Let $v=y'$. Then the second order ODE reduce to a first order ODE (ignore the BC first), then solve it using integrating factor.
